# Masonry IE9 showing only one column, always

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

My Masonry has only one column in ie9, always, though in Firefox it displays columns fine. I put a simple example in the Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vNXGB/

It's the same, with or without float:left.  It seems to be the same no matter which of three imagesLoaded scripts I tried, and whether or not I have images:

https://gist.github.com/1539102

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/

https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

So that leaves a problem in my Fiddle code?  I tried applying the CSS elsewhere, I tried resetting IE settings to default, clearing IE cache, uploading my site so it's not on localhost, etc.

Any ideas?  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Jennifer,

I would just add that this problem/solution also applies to Metafizzy's Packery. I haven't tested Isotope but I wouldn't be surprised if you found it there as well.

Answer (score 8):

Well in case anyone else got permanently stuck at this point too, here's the answer from desandro (the author):

> Thanks for submitting this bug :)
>
> Looks like this was caused by some CSS
>
> .brick { margin: 0 auto 10px auto; }
>
> Those auto caused IE to measure the brick's width as taking up the
>   entire width of the container. Changing it to margin: 0 0 10px 0;
>   seemed to fix it.
>
> see http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/sflJa